# Qt Maps Code Not Working

Tags: qt, google-maps, qt4, google-maps-api-3, maps

I found one sample Qt maps project, my requirement is exactly similar to it.the code is getting built, but map is not displaying.  Here is the [`source code link`](http://efforts.embedded.ufcg.edu.br/qt/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/showmap.zip).

The description of the sample project is provided [`here`](http://efforts.embedded.ufcg.edu.br/qt/?p=80). So please tell me what is missing in the code, i appreciate your help.

Comment: Any error messages in your server log files?  How about in your browser JavaScript console?

Comment: I think its fine. but i have not checked all these.. i just built code and try to run.. can you please download code from above link and try running in ur machine will it work or not pls tell.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the code and built it (on Windows with qmake and nmake). It works on my machine (Windows7/64, Qt-4.7.3, VS2010Express).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.. hey are u able to see those places when u click on button?